# increment a value when a button is clicked and update a text field with that value

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, textfield

I'm stuck on an assignment where I will need to have a text field update each time a user clicks on a button. In total there are 5 buttons, each with their own text field that should be updated when they are clicked on. The issue that I am having is that the counter does not seem to update the text field when clicked multiple times. So the first time I click the button, the text field will say "1", but it stays like that after multiple clicks.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
   {                                                     
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          int snickers = 0;
          int butterfinger = 0;
          int lays = 0;
          int coke = 0;
          int dietCoke = 0;
          int totalItems = 0;
          double totalPrice = (totalItems * PRICE);

          if (e.getSource() == snickersButton)   
          {
                 totalItems++;                    

                 snickers++;                     
                 quantityTextS.setText(String.valueOf(snickers));        //Display snickers value in text field
                 itemsSelectedText.setText(String.valueOf(totalItems));  //Display total items value in text field 

              if(snickers > MAX)                
              {  
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The maximum number of each item that can be selected is 3.", 
                  "Invalid Order Quantity", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                  quantityTextS.setText("3");     //Set text to 3 
              }
          }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because you declare `snickers` and `totalItems` as local fields of `actionPerformed` method so they will be created and initilized to 0 every time you click. Consider one of the following approach:

1. Make these fields static fields of the class
2. Get the `snickers` and `totalItems` from the current buttons, parse them to int values and compute based on those values

Answer (score 3):

All your "counters" are local variables, so they will be re-initalised each time `actionPerformed` is called

You should make the counters instance fields instead...

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
   {                                                     
      private int snickers = 0;
      private int butterfinger = 0;
      private int lays = 0;
      private int coke = 0;
      private int dietCoke = 0;
      private int totalItems = 0;
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          double totalPrice = (totalItems * PRICE);

          if (e.getSource() == snickersButton)   
          {
```

This assumes, though, you are using the same instance of `ButtonListener` for ALL your buttons

Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details

Comment: Yes, I am using the same ButtonListener on each button. Thanks so much, my counters are working now.

Answer (score 0):

Add action listener to your button

```
buttonName.addActionListener(this);
```

also, write the variable that holds the value to be displayed as Global variable. Don't declare in inside the function

try this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class DrawOval implements ActionListener
{

    JButton genderBtn = new JButton("gender");
    JFrame frm = new JFrame();  
    JTextField displayTF = new JTextField(15);

    int i = 0;



    public DrawOval(){

        displayTF.setText(""+i);
        frm.setTitle("Grocery");
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setSize(200,100);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setResizable(true);
        frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frm.add(displayTF);
        frm.add(genderBtn);
        genderBtn.addActionListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(ae.getSource() == genderBtn){
            i++;
            displayTF.setText(""+i);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new DrawOval();
    }


}
```